# Python input function keeps on taking input even after EOF?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I just started learning python and am facing an error, i don't know how to resolve.
I just wrote a code which simply asks the user to enter a number,using input function.

```
a=input("enter the number:")
print("The number you entered:")
print(a)
```

and the output for this is

```
enter the number:101
4645
65465464564654654
54545445
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uw6Ay.jpg)

It just doesn't go to print statement, it keeps on taking the input for variable a. Please help...
I am using pycharm to write the code.

Comment: it worked fine here, try running from command e.g. python test.py

Comment: EOF or carriage return (i.e. enter/return)? Or are you pressing ctrl+d at the end of your input?

Comment: @WayneWerner on Windows it would be Ctrl+Z.

Comment: I gave the input 105 and pressed enter but it didn't go to the print statement(2nd line)

Comment: It worked fine on IDLE (line by line successfully executed) but in pycharm, it keeps on taking input.

Comment: Sounds like a pycharm bug. What version of pycharm are you using?

Comment: currently using Pycharm 2017.1

Comment: Yeah, I just updated pycharm and it got fixed. It was a bug.Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I got your question right but you can try writing:

```
a = input("enter the number:")
print ("The number you entered:" , a)
```

and running it in shell. You'll be able to get the output:

```
enter the number:101
The number you entered: 101
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I just updated pycharm and it got fixed. It was a bug.Thanks for your help.